# I just wanted to verify the general idea for setting up the solution to an inhomogeneous PDE with inhomogeneous boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For the inhomogeneous steady-state PDE with linear differential operator $D$, $Du(x,y) = Q(x,y)$ with inhomogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions $u|_{\partial\Omega} = \alpha$, to find the solution, we split up $u(x,y)$ into its particular and complementary parts: $$\tag{1} u(x,y) = u_0(x,y) + v(x,y)$$

where $v(x,y)$ is the *particular* solution to the PDE subjected to homogeneous boundary conditions $v|_{\partial\Omega} = 0$, and $u_0(x,y)$ is the *complementary* solution subjected to inhomogeneous boundary conditions $u_0|_{\partial\Omega} = \alpha$.

Is this correct? I know it works this way for ODEs, but wanted to verify if this was still the case for PDEs before proceeding.

Comment: As long as $D$ is linear, you still have superposition of solutions going for you.

Comment: @Aruralreader Great! Thank you!